# Handling STX-ETX frame with Netty

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, tcp, netty

Have to implement the following TCP/IP protocol implementation with Netty:

```
Message structure:
The messages are embedded in an STX-ETX frame:

STX    MESSAGE      ETX
0x02   7b20224d...  0x03   

An `escaping` of STX and ETX within the message is not necessary since it is in JSON format

Escape sequence are following:
```

> JSON.stringify ({"a": "\ x02 \ x03 \ x10"}) → "{" a \ ": " \ u0002 \ u0003 \ u0010 \ "}".

Here is more info about [STX, ETX control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX).

Length of the message could be different and it will have JSON format, something like:

> \0x02{"messageID": "Heartbeat"}\0x03

My idea was made a combination of custom Frame delimiter with StringEncoder/StringDecoder.

For custom Frame delimiter -> use `0x03` as a delimiter and skip the first byte (0x02).

So created the following `FrameDelimiterDecoder`:

```
@Slf4j
public class FrameDelimiterDecoder extends DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder {

    public FrameDelimiterDecoder(int maxFrameLength, ByteBuf delimiter) {
        super(maxFrameLength, delimiter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buffer) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buffFrame = null;

        Object frame = super.decode(ctx, buffer);
        if (frame instanceof ByteBuf) {
            buffFrame = (ByteBuf) frame;
        } else {
            log.info("frame: {}", frame);
        }

        if (buffFrame != null) {
            buffFrame.writeBytes(buffer.skipBytes(1));
        } else {
            log.warn("buffer is <null>");
        }

        return buffFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        log.error(cause.getMessage(), cause);
    }
}
```

And use it for initialisation:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QrReaderChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final StringEncoder stringEncoder = new StringEncoder();
    private final StringDecoder stringDecoder = new StringDecoder();

    private final QrReaderProcessingHandler readerServerHandler;
    private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast(new FrameDelimiterDecoder(1024 * 1024, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(FrameConstant.ETX)));

        if (nettyProperties.isEnableTimeout()) {
            pipeline.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(nettyProperties.getClientTimeout()));
        }
        pipeline.addLast(stringDecoder);
        pipeline.addLast(stringEncoder);
        pipeline.addLast(readerServerHandler);
    }
}
```

However, it always fails with:

```
c.s.netty.init.FrameDelimiterDecoder     : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(28) + length(1) exceeds writerIndex(28): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 28, widx: 28, cap: 1024)

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(28) + length(1) exceeds writerIndex(28): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 28, widx: 28, cap: 1024)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:471)
```

Could not understand what is missing there.

***How to process STX-ETX frame for request/response with Netty?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try and fails finally, solved this issue.

Rethink the code for `FrameDelimiterDecoder` and found the way how to do it with an array of bytes and at the end convert to `ByteBuf`. I believe it could be done with the buffer directly or to use ByteBuffer from NIO package and then convert.

The simplest for me was:

```
@Slf4j
public class FrameDelimiterDecoder extends DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder {
    public FrameDelimiterDecoder(int maxFrameLength, ByteBuf delimiter) {
        super(maxFrameLength, delimiter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buffer) {
        boolean inMessage = false;

        int size = buffer.readableBytes();

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
        buffer.readBytes(byteBuffer);

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[size - 2];
        byte[] data = byteBuffer.array();

        int index = 0;
        for (byte b : data) {
            if (b == FrameConstant.START_OF_TEXT) {
                if (!inMessage) {
                    inMessage = true;
                } else {
                    log.warn("Unexpected STX received!");
                }
            } else if (b == FrameConstant.END_OF_TEXT) {
                if (inMessage) {
                    inMessage = false;
                } else {
                    log.warn("Unexpected ETX received!");
                }
            } else {
                if (inMessage) {
                    byteArray[index] = b;
                    index += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(byteArray);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        if (cause instanceof InterruptedException) {
            log.warn("interrupted exception occurred");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } else {
            log.error("FrameDelimiterEncoder exception occurred:", cause);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `FrameConstant` look like:

```
@UtilityClass
public class FrameConstant {
    public final int START_OF_TEXT = 0x02;
    public final int END_OF_TEXT = 0x03;

    public final int MAX_FRAME_LENGTH = 1024 * 1024;
}
```

Then initialize it:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QrReaderChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    private final StringEncoder stringEncoder = new StringEncoder();
    private final StringDecoder stringDecoder = new StringDecoder();

    private final QrReaderProcessingHandler readerServerHandler;
    private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();

        // Add the delimiter first
        pipeline.addLast(getDelimiterDecoder());

        if (nettyProperties.isEnableTimeout()) {
            pipeline.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(nettyProperties.getClientTimeout()));
        }
        pipeline.addLast(stringDecoder);
        pipeline.addLast(stringEncoder);
        pipeline.addLast(readerServerHandler);
    }

    private FrameDelimiterDecoder getDelimiterDecoder() {
        ByteBuf delimiter = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{FrameConstant.END_OF_TEXT});
        return new FrameDelimiterDecoder(FrameConstant.MAX_FRAME_LENGTH, delimiter);
    }
}
```

And some modification for handler:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class QrReaderProcessingHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private final PermissionService permissionService;
    private final EntranceService entranceService;
    private final Gson gson;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        String remoteAddress = ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString();
        String stringMsg = (String) msg;

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("CLIENT_IP: {}", remoteAddress);
            log.debug("CLIENT_REQUEST: {}", stringMsg);
        }

        if (HEARTBEAT.containsName(stringMsg)) {
            HeartbeatResponse heartbeatResponse = buildHeartbeatResponse();
            sendResponse(ctx, heartbeatResponse);

        } 
    }

    private <T> void sendResponse(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, T response) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(formatResponse(response));
    }

    private <T> String formatResponse(T response) {
        String realResponse = String.format("%s%s%s",
                (char) FrameConstant.START_OF_TEXT,
                gson.toJson(response),
                (char) FrameConstant.END_OF_TEXT);

        log.debug("response: {}", realResponse);
        return realResponse;
    }
```

And finally, it sends correctly formed response back:

[image]